# mDNS on arduino: avahi mDNS daemon returning strange "Received conflicting record [...]. Resetting our record."

Tags: arduino, mdns

I'm trying to implement a lightweight mDNS announcer for arduino.
It should announce the "apple midi rtp" service.

Now the good part is that I can ping it my name (mymdnstest.local) most of the time and sometimes it shows up in the output of "avahi-browse -a".

Always the avahi-daemon shows in the systemd logging:

```
Received conflicting record [_apple-midi._udp.local        IN        PTR mymdnstest._apple-midi._udp.local ; ttl=120]. Resetting our record.".
```

tcpdump shows:

```
22:12:00.691720 wlo1  M   IP (tos 0x0, ttl 2, id 969, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 199)
192.168.65.215.5353 > 224.0.0.251.5353: [udp sum ok] 0*- [0q] 3/0/0 _apple-midi._udp.local. (Cache flush) [2m] PTR mymdnstest._apple-midi._udp.local., _apple-midi._udp.local. (Cache flush) [2m] SRV mymdnstest.local.:5004 0 0, mymdnstest.local. (Cache flush) [2m] A 192.168.65.215 (171)
```

What can it be that these errors are seen and that it behaves so randomly?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

char ssid[] = " my ssid ";
char pass[] = " password for my ssid ";

WiFiUDP udp;

const IPAddress tgt_ip { 224, 0, 0, 251 };
constexpr int tgt_port = 5353;

constexpr char name[] = "mymdnstest";
constexpr uint16_t port = 5004;

void update_mdns() {
    static uint32_t last_msg = 0;
    uint32_t now = millis();

    if (last_msg == 0 || now - last_msg >= 750) {
        last_msg = now;

        static bool state = true;
        digitalWrite(D0, state);  // blink led
        state = !state;

        uint8_t response[256];
        uint16_t ro = 0;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // transaction id
        response[ro++] = 0x00;

        response[ro++] = 0x84;  // standard query response, no error
        response[ro++] = 0x00;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // 0 questions
        response[ro++] = 0x00;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // 3 answers
        response[ro++] = 0x03;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // 0 authority rr
        response[ro++] = 0x00;
        
        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // 0 additional rr
        response[ro++] = 0x00;


        // PTR record
        constexpr char applemidi[] = "_apple-midi";
        constexpr char udp_[] = "_udp";
        constexpr char local[] = "local";

        response[ro++] = strlen(applemidi);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", applemidi);  // name itself
        response[ro++] = strlen(udp_);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", udp_);  // name itself
        response[ro++] = strlen(local);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", local);  // name itself
        response[ro++] = 0x00;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // PTR (12)
        response[ro++] = 0x0c;

        response[ro++] = 0x80;  // cache flush & class: in
        response[ro++] = 0x01;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // ttl 2 minutes
        response[ro++] = 0x00;
        response[ro++] = 0x00;
        response[ro++] = 0x78;

        uint16_t ptr_data_len = 1 + strlen(name) +
                    1 + strlen(applemidi) +
                    1 + strlen(udp_) +
                    1 + strlen(local) +
                    1;
        response[ro++] = ptr_data_len >> 8;
        response[ro++] = ptr_data_len;

        response[ro++] = strlen(name);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", name);  // name itself
        response[ro++] = strlen(applemidi);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", applemidi);  // name itself
        response[ro++] = strlen(udp_);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", udp_);  // name itself
        response[ro++] = strlen(local);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", local);  // name itself
        response[ro++] = 0x00;


        // SRV apple midi record
        response[ro++] = strlen(applemidi);  // length of name
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", applemidi);  // name itself

        response[ro++] = strlen(udp_);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", udp_);  // name itself

        response[ro++] = strlen(local);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", local);  // name itself

        response[ro++] = 0;  // string delimiter

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // type 33 SRV (server selection)
        response[ro++] = 0x21;

        response[ro++] = 0x80;  // class (cache flush: True, class: in)
        response[ro++] = 0x01;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // ttl 2 minutes
        response[ro++] = 0x00;
        response[ro++] = 0x00;
        response[ro++] = 0x78;

        uint16_t srv_data_len = 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + strlen(name) + 1 + strlen(local) + 1;
        response[ro++] = srv_data_len >> 8;  // data len
        response[ro++] = srv_data_len;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // priority
        response[ro++] = 0x00;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // weight
        response[ro++] = 0x00;

        response[ro++] = port >> 8;  // port on which the apple thing listens
        response[ro++] = port;

        response[ro++] = strlen(name);  // length of name
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", name);  // name itself

        response[ro++] = strlen(local);
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", local);  // name itself

        response[ro++] = 0x00;


        // A record for the hostname to the ip-address
        response[ro++] = strlen(name);  // length of name
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], "%s", name);  // name itself

        response[ro++] = strlen(local);  // length of "local"
        ro += sprintf((char *)&response[ro], local);

        response[ro++] = 0;  // string delimiter

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // type 0001 (A)
        response[ro++] = 0x01;

        response[ro++] = 0x80;  // class (cache flush: True, class: in)
        response[ro++] = 0x01;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // ttl 2 minutes
        response[ro++] = 0x00;
        response[ro++] = 0x00;
        response[ro++] = 0x78;

        response[ro++] = 0x00;  // length of address
        response[ro++] = 0x04;

        response[ro++] = WiFi.localIP()[0];
        response[ro++] = WiFi.localIP()[1];
        response[ro++] = WiFi.localIP()[2];
        response[ro++] = WiFi.localIP()[3];


        udp.beginPacketMulticast(tgt_ip, tgt_port, WiFi.localIP(), 2);
        udp.write(response, ro);
        udp.endPacket();
    }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(F("Go!"));

    pinMode(D0, OUTPUT);

    WiFi.hostname(name);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    static bool state = true;

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(100);
        Serial.print(F("."));

        digitalWrite(D0, state);
        state = !state;
    }

    digitalWrite(D0, false);

    Serial.println(F(""));

    Serial.print("IP address:\t");
    IPAddress myIP = WiFi.localIP();
    Serial.println(myIP);

    udp.beginMulticast(WiFi.localIP(), tgt_ip, 5353);
}

void loop() {
    update_mdns();
}
```

pcap: [https://vps001.vanheusden.com/~folkert/mdns.pcap](https://vps001.vanheusden.com/%7Efolkert/mdns.pcap)

Answer (score 0):

1. the flags of each RR were incorrect. only A and SRV should have clear cache
2. the hostname was missing from the SRV record

There is still a problem with it: rtpmidid signals a time-out when resolving the hostname but that doesn't fit this question.